# I need the best regular expression for this string with comma at the end

Tags: expression

We need to obtain WJCI2_SP (as example) in these two examples:

MeContext=WJCI2_SP,ManagedElement=1,TransportNetwork=1,Sctp=1

MeContext=WJCI2_SP
NetworkOfReference=SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=RNCATSB

Regular Expression used:  MeContext=([^,]+),

But this expression only match with the first example, not the second because we have not comma in the second case. How can I contemplate two options (a string after MeContext= that in one case ends with comma and in other cases not)?

Comment: Can you please clarify on what you need to match? Do you need the match the string 'WJCI2_SP' or any string that ends with comma (,)?

Comment: any string after MeContext= that ends with comma or without comma, because the actual regular expression only works in the first case, not the second, by the comma.

Comment: In the second case, we have not a comma in the end of the line/string and in this case we want extract WJCI2_SP (as example, could be WATR3_PK or RNCPA02)